# Invalid relational operator

Tags: oracle, jdbc

I use a prepare statement to execute an update statement.

```
PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        stmt = connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE " + table + " SET date = ?, id = ?, n = ? " +
                "WHERE (id_v = ?) AND (id_vid = ?)");
        stmt.setDate(1, n.getDate());
        stmt.setInt(2, n.getId());
        stmt.setInt(3, n.getN());
        stmt.setInt(4, n.getId_v());
        stmt.setInt(5, n.getId_vid());
        stmt.executeUpdate();
        stmt.close();
```

but I get an exception j`ava.sql.SQLException: ORA-00920: invalid relational operator`

What's wrong with my code?

p.s table is string parametre that I pass through the method

**edit**
The problem was resolved by using simple Statement(but not PrepareStatement) and inserting parametres to sql UPDATE via concatenation. SQL script of declaring the tables has been generated from physical data model diagram by Power Designer. It creates table fields as "date", "id_v", "id" and so on, so the problem was not in date field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it should be `AND (id_vid = ?)` for the second condition?

Right now, it says `AND (id vid = ?)` which is probably a typo.

Comment: no, the problem is not in such place. I have mistaked when typing this code in post. But in code it hasn't such mistake

Answer (score 2):

Do you really have a column named "date"? If so, it's not a great practice. The only way I could get it to work was to do:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE tt (ID integer, "DATE" DATE);

Table created

SQL> insert into tt values (1, null);

1 row inserted

SQL> update tt set "DATE" = sysdate where id = 1;

1 row updated

SQL> select * from tt;

    ID DATE
------ ---------
     1 14-Apr-11

SQL>
```

Comment: If you follow this path, please note that when you quote an identifier it becomes case sensitive in Oracle. `My_Column` and `MY_COLUMN` both refer to the same column, `"My_Column"` and `"MY_COLUMN"` do not.

Comment: And I would not recommend following this path at all. Case sensitive identifiers are a pain on a lot of levels, and columns named reserved words like "DATE" or "INTEGER" are a bad idea.